# Deleting file from folder

Tags: php, unlink, delete-file

I'm not quite sure where the problem lies.
But the code won't unlink the file :(

```
 <?php include_once("sessions.php");
require_once("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

$album_id = $_SESSION['album_id'];

$checkbox = $_POST['photo_checkbox'];
$count = count($checkbox);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $id = (int) $checkbox[$i]; // Parse your value to integer

    if ($id > 0) { // and check if it's bigger then 0

        $query = "SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            $file = $row['path'];

                if(!unlink($file)){
                    $_SESSION["edit_message"] = "<br>Something went wrong while deleting shit ... please try your editing again." .$file;
                    header ("Location: ../fotos.php?album=".$album_id."");
                    exit;
                }

            }
        $query = "DELETE FROM media WHERE id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
}   

    if($result){
        $_SESSION["edit_message"] = "<br>Successfully deleted !";
        header ("Location: ../fotos.php?album=".$album_id."");
        exit;}
}

?>
```

If I take out the unlink loop part and just go straight to the deleting from the db it works fine.
What am I missing?
Might it be the permissions that are hindering the code from executing ?

EDIT :
Changed the permissions of the file to 0777 now. So it should really work ...
But still doesn't seem to. ! :/
I have no ideas now.
Maybe the loop isn't working properly ?

Thanx for your help

Cheers

Chris

Comment: so you get the redirect and the "something went wrong" message? Check the permissions on the file, and the directory it's in. You need to have the rights on both (e.g. write perms on the containing dir).

Comment: Yeah I get the redirect and the "something went wrong" message :/

Comment: `echo $file = $row['path'];` see what you get and if it doesn't match the file and path, then you'll know what's wrong.

Comment: Have done the echo part already and the dil path seems to be ok.

Comment: It's most likely a permissions issue then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: could I change the chmod like so     $file2 = chmod($file, 0777); before deleting it ?

Comment: You could try that, I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: You need execute rights on the parent folder

Comment: rights on the parent folder are 0777 just can't change permissions on the file

Comment: Who did create the file? The PHP process or you on the FTP?

Comment: The php process did. So now I have to change the owner of the File I guess to then be able to change the permissions...right ?

Comment: Edited the question, after changing the permissions...still doesn't work :/

Comment: If the php process is the owner then he should be able to unlink the file cause it's the owner by default... Are u sure the file exists?

Answer (score 1):

```
$file2 = chmod($file, 0777);

if(!unlink($file2)){
```

$file2 is getting the return value of chmod, which is a bool.  You're then trying to unlink a true/false value.  Perhaps you meant to unlink($file) ?

Edit to reflect your changes:

If $file is not a fully qualified path name $file will be relative to the current working directory of where ever the script is running from.  Ensure $file is a full path name.

Comment: So it should look like so : 
    $file = $row['path'];
    $file = chmod($file, 0777); 
      if(!unlink($file)){
     Hmmm I'm getting confused

Answer (score 1):

Write permissions on the file are not sufficient you need **write permissions on the directory** itself to be able to delete a file within it.

You should first check the file exists, you should then check that you have the correct permissions on the directory NOT the file.

```
if(file_exists($file) && is_writeable(dirname($file))){
unlink($file);
}else{
//invalid path or permission problems
}
```